# Adding line breaks and white space to string programmatically

Tags: python, string, replace

I have a string with multiple line breaks in it. An example looks as follows:

```
s = "This is a conversation between a Human and person alpha.\n\n1) Human: Hello\n2)person alpha:What's up?\n3)Human:Not much, how about you?4) person alpha: I'm watching TV.\n5) Human: What are you watching?\n6) person alpha: I'm watching a series7)Human: Interesting."
```

Before each Human and personal alpha there should be a line break. In addition, sometimes the space after the colon is missing. The correct string should look as follows:

```
s = "This is a conversation between a Human and person alpha.\n\n1) Human: Hello\n2)person alpha: What's up?\n3) Human: Not much, how about you?\n4) person alpha: I'm watching TV.\n5) Human: What are you watching?\n6) person alpha: I'm watching a series\n7)Human: Interesting."
```

I've tried to achieve it by using `replace("Human:", "Human: ")` and `replace("person alpha:", "person alpha: ")` but this introduces additional whitespace when there is already a correct whitespace. For line break, I would like to add a "\n" for every x) where x is a number and if it does not yet have a "\n".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using regular expressions (not exactly the same as OP's expected output, but better!)

```py
import re
# input string
s = "This is a conversation between a Human and person alpha.\n\n1) Human: Hello\n2)person alpha:What's up?\n3)Human:Not much, how about you?4) person alpha: I'm watching TV.\n5) Human: What are you watching?\n6) person alpha: I'm watching a series7)Human: Interesting."
# add/remove missing/redundant spaces after colon
ss = re.sub(r'(Human|person alpha):\s*', r'\1: ', s)
# add/remove missing/redundant newlines before number
ss = re.sub(r'\n*(\d+)\)\s*', r'\n\1) ', ss)
print(ss)
```

The output should be:

```
This is a conversation between a Human and person alpha.
1) Human: Hello
2) person alpha: What's up?
3) Human: Not much, how about you?
4) person alpha: I'm watching TV.
5) Human: What are you watching?
6) person alpha: I'm watching a series
7) Human: Interesting.
```

Answer (score 2):

> sometimes the space after the colon is missing ... this introduces additional whitespace when there is already a correct whitespace

Use regex to replace *all* trailing spaces with one space

```
>>> import re
>>> def repl_colon(match):
...   return match.group(1) + ': '
...
>>> re.sub(r'(alpha|Human):\s*', repl_colon, "person alpha:1 Human: 2 Human:  3")
'person alpha: 1 Human: 2 Human: 3'
```

Repeat for all other patterns you're interested in.

> add a "\n" for every `x)` where `x` is a number and if it does not yet have a "\n".

That will be more difficult unless you have conditions around each statement. For example, "season 1", here: `6) person alpha: I'm watching season 17)Human: Interesting.`